# Cannot see where is the error in my simple code

Tags: python

In the following, why it is not printing results even though I don't see any errors:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def printing(self):
        var = self.x + self.y
        print(" RESULT= %i " % var)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().printing(10, 20)
```

Comment: Your first order of business is to figure out why you're not seeing any errors; that code should definitely generate one.

Comment: Yes I just noticed my mistake. I just don't know why I could not spot it. I apologize

Comment: Wait, when you said "I don't see any errors", did you mean "I think my code is right even though there is an error", or do you mean "it generated no errors"?  I thought you meant the second and that something was wrong with your Python setup.  If you see that your code is generating an exception, you should always copy and paste it into your questions

Comment: I meant it generated no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().printing(10, 20)
```

Should be

```
Test(10, 20).printing()
```

You have mistake in instance initialization.